# Script hangs after query that takes long time to execute

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have problems with a script in PowerShell that hangs after executing MySQL SELECT query, that takes in cases more than 10 minutes to execute.

```bsh
$query = "SELECT S.DESCRIPTION, date_format(N.TIMESTAMP, '%H'), count(*)
    FROM NOTIFICATIONS N, SENDING_TYPE S
    WHERE N.ID_SENDING_TYPE = S.ID_SENDING_TYPE
    AND N.TIMESTAMP > date_format ('"+$fecha+"', '%Y%m%d')
    GROUP BY S.DESCRIPTION, date_format(N.TIMESTAMP, '%H')"
```

Example - `$fecha="20170630"`

I execute the query with my function (here is where PowerShell hangs)

```bsh
$resultado = Get-QueryMysql -Servidor $MySQLHost -Port $port -UserName $MySQLAdminUserName -Password $MySQLAdminPassword -DataBase $MySQLDatabase -Query $query
```

Here's the function `Get-QueryMysql`:

```bsh
function Get-QueryMysql {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param(
        # Servidor Mysql
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Servidor,

        # Puerto Oracle
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Port,

        # ServiceName
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$DataBase,

        # Usuario
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$UserName,

        # Password
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Password,

        # Query
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Query,

        # If Allow zero datetime
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$AllowZeroDateTime,

        # Reintentos
        # Query
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int]$Reintentos=10,

        [switch]$AntiguoMysql
    )

    Begin {
        # Load the ODP assembly
        if ($AntiguoMysql.IsPresent) {
            Add-Type -Path C:\TRABAJO\REPORTES\modules\MySQL\mysql.data.dll -IgnoreWarnings
        } else {
            $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
        }
    }

    Process {
        # Cadena de conexion
        $ConnectionString = "server=" + $Servidor + ";port=$port;uid=" + $UserName + ";pwd=" + $Password + ";database=" + $DataBase

        if ($AllowZeroDateTime.IsPresent) {
            $ConnectionString = "server=" + $Servidor + ";port=$port;uid=" + $UserName + ";pwd=" + $Password + ";database="+$DataBase+";Allow Zero Datetime=True"
        }

        $cont = 0
        for ($i=0; $i-lt $Reintentos; $i++) {
            $MysqlConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
            $MysqlConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
            $MysqlConnection.Open()

            $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $MysqlConnection)
            $DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
            $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
            $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($DataSet, "data")

            if ($DataSet) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$dataSet) {
            Write-Host "ERROR: Conectando a la BBDD"
            return $null
        }

        # Datos obtenidos
        return $DataSet.Tables[0]
    }

    End {
        # Cerrando Conexiones
        if ($MysqlConnection) {
            $MysqlConnection.Close()
            $MysqlConnection.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

The query is a SELECT that filters by timestamp field. I tried to change the structure of the table, but my requirement in a production environment was denied. So I need to do that my script works, I only have problems with queries that takes a long time.

I try using script-block command but it doesn't work.

When process is executing the cpu is in 0.5% and 20 mb of ram (Doesn't have increment).

When I execute the query from DBMS (Navicat) it takes 10 minutes, in somes cases more than that. I checked the MySQL database with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and the query executed by the script finished succesfully after minutes, but the PowerShell script hangs.

---

The script hangs after execute the following line:

```bsh
$RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
```

---

After load another connector:

```bsh
[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\modules\MySQL\6.9.8\mysql.data.dll")
```

the scripts doesn't hang, but now it happens an error exception:

```bsh
Exception "Fill" arguments "2": "Fatal error encountered during command execution."
+             $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlException
```

Seeing the timeout variable in database, is setted to 8 hours:

```bsh
interactive_timeout=28800
wait_timeout=28800
```

The `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command shows that the connection is in `Sending Data` state.

The **Error Exception** only occurs when the query take over 1 minute or more..

Answer (score 0):

@Steve_MSFT answered this on Twitter:

> [Based on your details, it seems like an issue in that cmdlet.  You need to contact the owner of that module.](https://twitter.com/Steve_MSFT/status/890998136973307904)